# Need explanation for C++ code

Tags: c++

```
namespace Stack {
  struct Rep; // definition of stack layout is elsewhere
  typedef Rep& stack;
  stack create(); // make a new stack
  void destroy(stack s); // delete s
  void push(stack s, char c); // push c onto s
  char pop(stack s); // pop s
}
```

This is in the "A Tour of C++" Unit, before even the basic material like functions, loops, and fundamental datatypes...I don't know if/how I'm supposed to understand this code or not.

Anyway, can someone please explain it? It's supposed to be part of an explanation on how to "define a stack manager with an interface"

For starters, I specifically don't know what "`typedef Rep& stack`" means.

Comment: Whatever course this is, find another.

Comment: It means this piece of code is severely broken and does memory management in an opaque way.

Comment: It's the book by C++ founder, Bjarne Stroustrup! lol!

Comment: @wajed Well, that is sad. But I must admit, with the exception of D&E, I've never thought much of his books.

Comment: @wajed: Just because the author was the original C++ developer doesn't mean he actually knows what he's doing (C++ is a mess!) or that he's good at writing books.

Comment: @wajed - Ok, so you have found an introductory chapter and don't get it all after 10 pages? There is another 1000 pages in that book, with more in-depth explanations. Keep reading!

Comment: @Mayank - He has read the first half of chapter 2 of ["The C++ Programming language"](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) and he doesn't get it all yet. Bad book?

Comment: This is actually shown as a bad example in the book

Comment: @Dikei: Oh, that makes so much more sense!

Comment: Actually, this just shows how BS does not know how to write teaching materials - you don't show bad practice as part of an introduction. And I know whereof I speak - I used to have to teach a C course that had Duff's Device in the first unit, until I got it removed.

Comment: How funny! I'm reading this book at this section and I have the exactly same question!

Answer (score 7):

In short, `stack` is a typedef for a reference to the type `Rep`. That means, whenever you use `stack`, you denote the type "reference to Rep".

In my opinion, this is a weird C++ course material. From what the interface looks like, we can suppose the implementation will be something like

```
/* in darkcorner.cpp: */


stack create() { // make a new stack
  stack s = *new Rep;
  return s;
}

void destroy(stack s) { // delete s
  delete &s;
}

void push(stack s, char c) { // push c onto s
  s.push(c);
}

char pop(stack s) { // pop s
  return s.pop();
}
```

Now, if you do the following, you violate the principle of least surprise for most C++ programmers.

```
stack p = create();
stack p2 = p;
```

The "principle of least surprise" says that this shall copy the stack. But actually, `stack` stands for the type `Rep&`, which is a "reference to Rep". This means that the second line creates an alias to `p` (reference to what `p` refers to). It doesn't copy, but just creates another reference.

I recommend you: Stay clear of such code. If you want to hide the implementation or layout of `Rep`, then implement the [Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom#C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 3):

`typedef Rep& stack` means that `stack` will be a synonym for `Rep&`. So instead of

```
Rep &r;
```

you can write

```
stack r;
```

**Update:** `Rep &r` means that `r` is a reference to object of type `Rep`.

For example:

```
Rep rep; // object of type (class) Rep
Rep &ref = rep; // reference to rep
```

BTW. I don't like the code you have posted.

1. `typedef`ing something just to make it a reference is not a good idea; it should be clearly visible that something is a pointer or reference, because then it behaves in much other way than it looks like.
2. `push()` and `pop()` should be methods of class `Rep` (or better `Stack`), or it is more C code than C++ :)
3. memory management; you have to care that `destroy()` will be called for every stack you got from `create()`. Usually smart pointers are used to ensure proper memory management.

Comment: I understand, but what does "Rep& r" mean?

Comment: @wajed - Bjarne tells you all that if you just keep reading on the same page as the code!

Answer (score 1):

You're in a namespace called 'Stack', so as to keep all any of the symbols you declare from being global and potentially clashing with other symbols.

`struct Rep` is a forward declaration that says that there is a type of struct named Rep defined properly somewhere else, and that's the one you'll be referring to even if you don't know exactly what layout it has here.

`typedef Rep& stack` makes 'stack' a literal synonym of 'Rep &', as Messa has already answered. So everywhere you write 'stack' it's the same as writing 'Rep &'. `Rep &` means a reference to a struct of type 'Rep'. The size of the reference will be known even without knowing the full definition of Rep so the forward declaration isn't a problem.

The four remaining lines declare functions that, presumably, will perform the operations the names suggest and as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of showing C coders how C++ Objects formed; `namespace Stack { struct Rep; }` will give you a `Stack::Rep` item/object which is similar to doing `class Stack { struct Rep;}`.  If you are not familiar with C and namespaces then it does seem an odd example to have at the start of the book.

Anyway that is my best guess as when I first saw this after using C for a while I realised "Oh, that is how objects sort of came about.  They are namespaces with some extra fun added in to the compiler!"

Answer (score 0):

`typedef Rep& stack` means that in namespace `Stack` if you use `stack` it would mean its type is `Rep&`. It is like assigning a type to a word.